# Modelling a scenario where an admin can control read-only / view / defaults for certain user-input fields on web pages?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I would like the admins to control default values, and determine whether an input field is defaulted / can be written/seen by users.

A couple of ideas I had were to:

- Include one 'default' record that the admins can update, and then grab the values every time a user creates a new entry. In this scenario I'm not sure how to control readonly/view.
- Create a structure that uses 'field' objects, and in the 'field', include bools for read-only/viewable, and a field for the actual field type and default. The downside is that the table that holds the users' entries would be a subset of this set of objects. Also I am not sure how complex this structure is going to end up being, with regard to client/server validations, etc.

If it matters, we are using ASP.net MVC3, with Code-First Entity Framework 4.1. Another idea was to change the annotations at runtime, which seems complicated and maybe hard to maintain/easy to screw up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that I will be implementing soon, so I have been thinking about it some. Here are my ideas. I haven't implemented anything yet or researched which (if any) of these ideas will work, so please receive them that way.

First, I figured I would have a stored procedure that would read the data from the security tables in the database and return it in a standardized format. This data could then be put into object that will be stored in Application (somewhere that will persist between requests) to be used on future requests.

Next, I would create either editor templates or html helpers that would use the stored security information to determine whether to display read only/editable and whether to display the default value or not.

Again, please remember that these are just my initial thoughts that have not been researched or implemented yet.

Hope this helps out.